# ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am playing around with the ReactJS framework on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/).

I have noticed that if my component name starts with a lowercase letter it does not work.

For instance the following does not render:

```
var fml = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <a href='google.com'>Go</a>
  }
});

React.render(<fml />, document.body);
```

But as soon as I replace the `fml` with `Fml` it does render.

Is there a reason I cannot begin tags with small letters?

Comment: check the answers of this question for some more detials: [Html is not rendering in the browser - React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/html-is-not-rendering-in-the-browser-react-js)

Answer (score 261, accepted):

In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. However, lower-case tag names with a dot (property accessor) aren't.

See [HTML tags vs React Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components).

- `<component />` compiles to `React.createElement('component')` (html tag)
- `<Component />` compiles to `React.createElement(Component)`
- `<obj.component />` compiles to `React.createElement(obj.component)`

Comment: Add another half an hour to the counter. I was going insane, trying to render something like `let component = components[compType]; <component/>`, and getting nonsense errors.

Comment: I've tried `<components[name] />` which doesn't work either.

Comment: I can't believe that I did not notice there is such a rule before.

Comment: This is a bad idea. I am being polite here.

Comment: Yep this could be extremely off-putting to n00bs since, if calling `Components` instead of `components`, their lovely site will load with no errors but no content!

Answer (score 68):

**@Alexandre Kirszenberg** gave a very good answer, just wanted to add another detail.

React used to contain a whitelist of well-known element names like `div` etc, which it used to differentiate between DOM elements and React components.

But because maintaining that list isn't all that fun, and because web components makes it possible to create custom elements, they made it **a rule that all React components must start with a upper case letter, or contain a dot**.

Comment: great info, even better if there's a official doc reference. thanks.

Comment: when was this changed?

Comment: Here's an official reference: "We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX." https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Answer (score 18):

From the [official React reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

Also note that:

> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

Which means one has to use:

`const Foo = foo;` before using `foo` as a Component element in JSX.

Answer (score 9):

> User define components must be Capitalized

When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string '`div`' or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

React recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in `JSX`.

> For example, this code will not run as expected:

```
import React from 'react';

// Wrong! This is a component and should have been capitalized:
function hello(props) {
  // Correct! This use of <div> is legitimate because div is a valid HTML tag:
  return <div>Hello {props.toWhat}</div>;
}

function HelloWorld() {
  // Wrong! React thinks <hello /> is an HTML tag because it's not capitalized:
  return <hello toWhat="World" />;
}
```

> To fix this, we will rename hello to Hello and use `<Hello />` when
> referring to it:

```
import React from 'react';

// Correct! This is a component and should be capitalized:
function Hello(props) {
  // Correct! This use of <div> is legitimate because div is a valid HTML tag:
  return <div>Hello {props.toWhat}</div>;
}

function HelloWorld() {
  // Correct! React knows <Hello /> is a component because it's capitalized.
  return <Hello toWhat="World" />;
}
```

Here is the [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: This answer is better because it holds all the information and it it the only one that link to the exact head in the documentation instead of the whole page. The comments in the code example may be a bit much for quick readability so if they would be understandable in a glance this answer would be perfect. (they may help beginners though)

Answer (score 7):

The first part of a `JSX` tag determines the type of the React element, basically there is some convention **Capitalized, lowercase, dot-notation**.

**Capitalized and dot-notation types** indicate that the `JSX` tag is referring to a React component,
 so if you use the JSX `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` 
 OR 
 `<foo.bar />` compile to `React.createElement(foo.bar)` and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

While the **lowercase type** indicate to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string `'div'` or `'span'` passed to `React.createElement('div')`.

React recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter,
 assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in `JSX`.

Answer (score 5):

In JSX, React Classes are capitalized to make XML compatible, so that it is not mistaken for an HTML tag. If the react classes are not capitalized, it is an HTML tag as pre-defined JSX syntax.