# react native - expected a component class, got [object Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got  expected a component class got object error when I try to use loginPage component which I created.

here is index.ios.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    AppRegistry,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import loginPage from './pages/loginPage'

class app extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <loginPage/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => app);
```

and here is the loginPage.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

export default class loginPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Welcome to React Native!
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: classes must be Capitalize, change it and lemme know the update.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You need to rename your `loginPage` class to `LoginPage`, the class must be **capitalize**

Comment: Amazing Answer !

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, but why is this the case?

Comment: @BenBieler Here is the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters

Comment: so how does it work with the default created with react-native init firstapp?

Answer (score 4):

**loginPage.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View
} from 'react-native';

const LoginPage = () => {
    return (
        <View>
                <Text>
                    Welcome to React Native!
                </Text>
            </View>
    );
}
export default LoginPage;
```

**index.ios.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    AppRegistry,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import LoginPage from './pages/loginPage'

class app extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <LoginPage/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the  tags in  `index.ios.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    AppRegistry,
    View
} from 'react-native';

import loginPage from './pages/loginPage'

class app extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

                <loginPage/>

        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('app', () => app);
```

Comment: Well, I somehow cannot edit this because the edit is less than 6 characters (thanks SO) but the `<View></View>` tags you are reffering to are not rendering.