# undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm trying to learn react native for the first time.  I tried to introduce a stacknavigator but the line `const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;` is causing the error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Login",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#000000"
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: "#fff"
    }
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const myscreens = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: App }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent("app", () => myscreens);
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

I should also mention that props is empty in the render function and in the constructor.

**here's my package.json incase it matters**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.48.3",
    "react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.0.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

And here's my index.android.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import App from './components/app';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class myapp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <App />
    );
  }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => myapp);
```

Comment: I just created a brand new project with just `react-navigation` installed and got no error. Perhaps post your `package.json`?

Comment: @MichaelCheng ok thanks i just added my package.json and my index.android.js.  Hopefully that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors:

1. You shouldn't be calling `AppRegistry` twice like that. You can remove it from your `app.js` file.
2. You are misunderstanding how `react-navigation`'s routers work. `StackNavigator` (and Tab and Drawer) are components that need to be rendered either directly (e.g., what you pass to `AppRegistry` [A]) or at some point in your application [B].

So to fix this, you will want to export `myscreens` instead of `App`. To illustrate both ways to do this:

**A.** You can see an example of this [in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/#Introducing-Stack-Navigator), but since you break up your code into two files, this is what it would look like:

**./components/app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Login',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: '#fff',
    },
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const myscreens = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: App },
});

export default myscreens;
```

**index.android.js**

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import myscreens from './components/app';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => myscreens);
```

**B.** You will render the `StackNavigator` in another class and then export the class that renders it. This fits more in line with what you are already doing and is more flexible in the long run (ex: you will need to do this if you use `redux` at some point), so you should probably do it this way:

**./components/app.js** - Note the casing change for `myscreens` to `MyScreens`. This is needed as React Native will [complain about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038751/react-native-expected-a-component-class-got-object-object) as [lowercase JSX tags are considered to be HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters). Using `AppRegistry` directly didn't trigger this error as you aren't using `myscreens` in JSX.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Login',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#000000',
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: '#fff',
    },
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const MyScreens = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: App },
});

export default MyScreens;
```

**index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import MyScreens from './components/app';

export default class myapp extends Component {
  render() {
    return <MyScreens />;
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => myapp);
```