# Is it possible to sub in any element type to JSX in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to create a super general component that can be built with any element type. ie, I'd like to do something like this:

```
const Wrapper = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const { props } = this;
    const elementType = props.elementType;
    return (
      <{elementType} className={className}>
        {props.children}
      </{elementType}>
    );
  }
});
```

but of course React gets very angry when I attempt this. Is there any way to build a component with to-be-decided HTML types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends very much on what `elementType` is. In JSX, you can either pass in a custom component itself, or a string (e.g. `h1`, `p`) as a "tag". In any case, you don't want to put the curly brackets `{}` around the tag. Very simple example:

```js
// Usually you want to import this. (This is just a stateless component)
const Element = (props) => <em>{props.children}</em>;

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { element1: 'h1', element2: Element };
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <this.state.element1>Hello!</this.state.element1>
        <this.state.element2>World!</this.state.element2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='View'></div>
```

If you want to use a string as a reference to a custom component, you will need to use native JavaScript with React's `createElement`/`cloneElement`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [React.createElement](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) to accomplish that (after all, JSX just provides syntactic sugar for it).

Something like that:

```
const myElement = React.createElement(

   /* type */
    props.elementType, //must be a string or a React Component class

    /* props object */
    { 
        className: className
    },

    /* You can pass children to the third parameter also. */
    props.children
);

return myElement;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can — even with JSX if you'd like.

The trick is to understand [how JSX is translated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505/179583) into the `React.createElement` calls:

- bracketed text starting with a **lowercase** character is translated into **a string**: `<div/>` becomes `React.createElement('div')`.
- bracketed text starting with an **uppercase** is assumed to be **a variable** in scope: `<SomeComponent/>` becomes `React.createElement(SomeComponent)`.

Now imagine if you assign `var SomeComponent = 'div'`. Then the uppercase rule would apply (passing the variable to `createElement`), *but* it will have the same effect as the first rule (because the variable references a string)!

Here's how it can look in a practical situation:

```
let Child = ({EL,thing}) => <EL className="helper-thing">{{ thing.name }}</EL>


let ListParent = ({things}) => <ul>
  {things.map(t => <Child EL='li' thing={t}/>)}
</ul>

let ArticleParent = ({things}) => <article>
  {things.map(t => <Child EL='p' thing={t}/>)}
</article>
```

See the official docs on [Choosing the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime) for a slightly different — perhaps cleaner — approach that capitalizes the property *inside* the child component.

Answer (score 0):

JSX does not allow this, but you can do it in pure Javascript React. You can create the component:

```
const element = React.createElement(elementType, {className}, props.children);
```

then return element from your render method. In fact, this is more or less what JSX would compile to, if it allowed you to do what you're proposing.

See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html for more discussion.