# Simple Component is not rendering: React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> I am tring to do react using below code but I am not getting html
>   element in the browser. There is no error in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>React without npm</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        var reactTest = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return(
                    <h1>React Without NPM</h1>
                );
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<reactTest />,document.getElementById('test'));
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can someone please help on this.

Answer (score 10):

If a React `Class name` starts with a `lowercase` letter then no methods inside the `class` get called, i.e. nothing Renders, and you don't get any error message in the Browser console,
because small letters are treated as `HTML` elements, its a rule that all `React components` must start with a `upper case` letter, so always use Upper Case.

Instead of `reactTest` use this: `ReactTest` it will work.

As per **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)**:

**User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized.**

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string 'div'
>   or 'span' passed to `React.createElement`. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to `React.createElement(Foo)` and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a
>   component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a
>   capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

Check the working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>React without npm</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        var ReactTest = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return(
                    <h1>React Without NPM</h1>
                );
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<ReactTest />,document.getElementById('test'));
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following works fine, try it  :

```js
      var ReactTest = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return(
                    <h1>React Without NPM</h1>
                );
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<ReactTest />,document.getElementById('test'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Some = ()=> <div />
<Some />
```

will work,
but

```
const some = () => <div />
<some />
```

won't work