# ReactDOM does not render a simple div

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a simple div on the main html file using ReactDOM render method, but the div is not rendered on the screen and there are no exceptions thrown. Am I doing it wrong?

app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1> Hi! </h1>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello World! </h1>
    <div id="root"></div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

The screen only shows the "Hello World!" h1 tag.

I'm also using webpack webpack dev server and Babel.

Comment: You haven't included `app.js` file in `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is you forgot to include your `bundle.js` file in `html`, add this line in body:

```
<script src = "bundle.js"></script>
```

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Example</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1> Hello World! </h1>
      <div id="root"></div> 
      <script src = "bundle.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Instead of `<!doctype html>` use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

**bundle.js**: When you run `webpack`, it starts the process from the entry point you defined in `webpack.config.js`, It will compile all your files and create a `bundle` file. You need to include that `bundle` in `html` file.

**Note**: change the path and file name if you are using name other than `bundle.js`.

Check this answer for user defined components: [Simple Component is not rendering: React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/simple-component-is-not-rendering-react-js/42110172#42110172)