# React property aren't working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

everyone!
I am building a simple one page app on react. It's the list of duties. Circles in this list are made in svg.

Unfortunately, React.js code doesn't working. It gives me an empty page.

There is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "bootstrap/MaterialDesign/css/materialdesignicons.css">

        <link href = "bootstrap/MaterialDesign/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot">
        <link href = "bootstrap/MaterialDesign/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.svg">
        <link href = "bootstrap/MaterialDesign/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf">
        <link href = "bootstrap/MaterialDesign/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff">
        <link href = "bootstrap/MaterialDesign/fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2">

        <script src = "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src = "bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js"></script>
        <script src = "react/react.js"></script>
        <script src = "react/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src = "react/browser.js"></script>

        <style>
            body{
                font-family:Arial;
                font-size: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "container-fluid">
            <div class = "col-sm-2">
                <div class = "well well-sm">TODO list
                    <svg style="width:24px;height:24px; align-content:right" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill="#000000" d="M19,4H15.5L14.5,3H9.5L8.5,4H5V6H19M6,19A2,2 0 0,0 8,21H16A2,2 0 0,0 18,19V7H6V19Z" />
                    </svg>
                </div>

                <div id = "list"></div>

                <svg style="width:24px;height:24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path fill="#000000" d="M19,13H13V19H11V13H5V11H11V5H13V11H19V13Z" />
                </svg><input type = "text"/>     
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type = "text/babel">

            var list = React.createClass ({
                render: function(){
                    return (<div>
                        <svg style="width:20px;height:20px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                            <path fill="#000000" d=[M12,20A8,8 0 0,1 4,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,4A8,8 0 0,1 20,12A8,8 0 0,1 12,20M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z] />
                        </svg>    
                        <p>{this.props.item}</p>
                    </div>
                    );
                }
            });

            ReactDOM.render(<div>
                                <list item = "Feed the dog" />
                                <list item = "Build the house" />
                                <list item = "Wash the car" />
                                <list item = "Make some shopping" />
                                <list item = "Build a list" />
                            </div>, 
            document.getElementById("list"));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: what error do you have in your console?

Comment: When running your code, I don't see any errors. Running Chrome 58 btw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html is not rendering in the browser - React js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/html-is-not-rendering-in-the-browser-react-js)

Answer (score 2):

React components must start with a upper case letter, so instead convert `list` variable to `List`.

If a React Class name starts with a lowercase letter then no methods inside the class get called, i.e. nothing Renders, and you don't get any error message in the Browser console. You will see the element in the DOM, but just empty contents

Comment: Still facing any issue in this?

Comment: Nice catch and explanation  +1