# React js - Why is navbar component not being imported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navbar

It works when I give the  part inside app.js but it shows blank screen when it is put in another file navbar.js and imported. If the code in navbar.js is directly added in app.js instead of importing, it works fine and navbar appears. Otherwise blank screen appears.

index.js is shown below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.js file

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import navbar from './navbar.js';

class home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
         <navbar />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default home;
```

navbar.js file:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Navbar} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Nav} from 'react-bootstrap';

class navbar extends Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <a href="#">React-Bootstrap</a>
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle />
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Nav>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link</NavItem>
          </Nav>
          <Nav pullRight>
            <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Link Right</NavItem>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>      
    );
  }
}
export default navbar;
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: i think class names should start with capital. Like Home, Navbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html is not rendering in the browser - React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/html-is-not-rendering-in-the-browser-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always start the name of your custom React components with 
a uppercase letter.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from './Navbar.js';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Navbar />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

and it's recommended to use the same name for the file name as well. So it should be `./Navbar.js` instead of `./navbar.js`

Read [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) from the official documentation for more information.

> Always start component names with a capital letter. For example, `<div/>` represents a DOM tag, but `<Welcome />` represents a component and
>   requires `Welcome` to be in scope.