# react got error of unknown props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to try stateless component in react, I split them into 2, but I got error of `Warning: Unknown props`items`on <renderItems> tag`

What's wrong with my code below?

```
import Items from './Items'
import Infinite from 'react-infinite'

const LeftPanel = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="leftPanel">
            <renderItems {...props} />
        </div>
    )
}

const renderItems = (props) => (
    <Infinite containerHeight={200} elementHeight={118}>
        {map(props.items, (item, index) => (
            <Items 
                index={index}
                item={item} 
            />
        ))}
    </Infinite>
)

export default LeftPanel
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html is not rendering in the browser - React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/html-is-not-rendering-in-the-browser-react-js) use `RenderItems` instead of `renderItems`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rename your `renderItems` to `RenderItems`.
I was seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505/6638533) and it looks like in `JSX` you need to put capital letter on the first word of your component name:

```
<component /> compiles to React.createElement('component') (html tag)
<Component /> compiles to React.createElement(Component)
```

Comment: instead of copy and pasting answer, mark the answer as duplicate :)

Comment: @MayankShukla ah I see, thanks for the insight. But what if the OP doesn't know that the cause is the letter case? Since in the link of the source answer, the title of the question is "ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?" (the OP there seems to know the cause), while here the OP doesn't know the cause. Shouldn't we put some answer for the cause? or should we just mark it as duplicate?

Comment: mention that in comment, *instead of `abc` use `Abc` check this answer for more details*, because that answer explained the issue very well :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntactic error in your code. You're using parenthesis in your functional component instead of curly braces.

```
const renderItems = (props) => {
    return (<Infinite containerHeight={200} elementHeight={118}>
        {map(props.items, (item, index) => (
            <Items 
                index={index}
                item={item} 
            />
        ))}
    </Infinite>);
}
```

Furthermore, lowercase component names are now deprecated so `renderItems` should be called `RenderItems`.

Comment: OP's code is correct, this will throw error, you are not returning anything inside `{}`.