# Simple “Hello World” in ReactJS not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am not getting hello world as an output. Can anyone tell me what i am missing  , its a basic code , got an output in a different way using createElement function. I am new to react.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My First App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="react-app"></div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>

        <script type="text/jsx">

            class StoryBox extends React.Component{
                render(){
                    return(<div> Hello World </div> );
                }
            }

            var target= document.getElementById('react-app')
            ReactDOM.render(<StoryBox>,target);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this `ReactDOM.render(<StoryBox />,target)` - notice closing the component off

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do these changes:

**1.** Include **[babel standalone script](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone)** to transform your jsx, put the cdn links in the head part, script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

**2.** Instead of `storyBox` use `StoryBox` (capital S), check this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/html-is-not-rendering-in-the-browser-react-js/42110172#42110172)** for reason.

**3.** You forgot to close, here: `<storyBox>`, use this: `<StoryBox />`.

**4.** Instead of `Div` use `div`.

Check the working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>My First App</title>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>

      <div id="react-app"></div>
      <script type="text/jsx">

         class StoryBox extends React.Component{
            render(){
               return(<div> Hello World </div> );
            }
         }

        var target= document.getElementById('react-app')
        ReactDOM.render(<StoryBox/>,target)

      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add babel as well, to transform your jsx into es5. Here is the sample code. NOTE: your cdn for react was throwing error so I have used other cdn.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. If you want to try react using npm packages [here](https://github.com/upasanaa/react-hello-world-example) is a simple github repository to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a `JSXTransformer` in order to be able to execute raw JSX. Try running the code below:

```
<div id="react-app">
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/react/0.14.0-rc1/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

<script type="text/jsx">
  class StoryBox extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(<div> Hello World </div> );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<StoryBox />, document.getElementById('react-app'))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add JSX self-closing tag `/>` - when there is no children.

replace this line:

```
ReactDOM.render(<StoryBox>,target)
```

to

```
ReactDOM.render(<StoryBox />,target)
```

See working code:

```js
class StoryBox extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(<div> Hello World </div>);
        }
    }
var target= document.getElementById('react-app')
ReactDOM.render(<StoryBox />,target)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="react-app"></div>
```