# Unable to view any output React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was watching a youtube tutorial for react everything was working fine then i refreshed my react app page and suddenly everything disappear from the browser, tried everything i and nothing works pls help.

code of App.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import Greet from './components/Greet';
import meet from './components/meet';


function App() {
  return (
    <div >
      <Greet />
      <meet />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

code of Greet.js:

```
import React from 'react';

// function Greet(){
//     return <h1> hello </h1>
// };

const Greet = () => {
    <div>
         <h1> Hello this is mj</h1>
    </div>
};

export default  Greet;
```

code of meet.js:

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';

class meet extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1> writing react </h1>
    }
};

export default meet;
```

[latest terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5kj2.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smoW7.png)

Comment: You've got a mix of function components and a class component. Is that intentional? `meet` should be `Meet` - React prefers component names to capitalised.

Comment: ya i am beginner learning both, it worked thank you so much

Comment: You have errors in the browser's console that you should fix

Comment: You're defining the `meet` component use a lowercase, note that in ReactJS component names must be in Pascal Case. That's to capitalize every first letter of word by convention. So meet component should be `<Meet />` and of course change the respective class name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple Component is not rendering: React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110144/simple-component-is-not-rendering-react-js)

Comment: still cant see the content of Greet.js

Comment: @MJ Can you update and detail what the current code now looks like and what errors if any are there in the terminal?

Comment: i am adding image in the question pls check

Comment: nothing in the console also

Comment: @MJ Check my answer.

Comment: got the error, i have to add the `className='App'` in div of file App.js

Comment: now everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

//Greet.js

```js
import React from "react";

// function Greet(){
//     return <h1> hello </h1>
// };

const Greet = () =>(
  <div>
    <h1> Hello this is mj</h1>
  </div>
);

export default Greet;
```

//Meet.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Meet extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1> writing react </h1>;
  }
}

export default Meet;
```

Your Greet and Meet file should look like this. In Greet.js you are not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining the meet component using lowercasing, note that in ReactJS component names should be in Pascal Case. That's to capitalize every first letter of a word by convention. So meet component should be  and of course change the respective class name.

And the `Greet.js` file component doesn't return the component. In functional components, you have to return the result of the component to be rendered.

The following is the correct code:

`Greet.js`

```js
import React from 'react';

// function Greet(){
//     return <h1> hello </h1>
// };

const Greet = () => {
   return (
    <div>
         <h1> Hello this is mj</h1>
    </div>
    );
};
```

`Meet.js`

```js
import React , { Component } from 'react';

class Meet extends Component {
    render() {
        return <h1> writing react </h1>
    }
};

export default Meet;
```

And finally, `App.js`

```js
import './App.css';
import Greet from './components/Greet';
import meet from './components/meet';


function App() {
  return (
    <div >
      <Greet />
      <Meet />
    </div>
  );
}
```