# html not rendering into dom in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. This is my first code where I am trying to render two components. I am not getting any error but HTML part is not coming up. DOM is empty. What is wrong here? --

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class First extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>it is about how to render two component. it is first component</h1>
        )
    }
}

class Second extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <h1>it is about how to render two component. it is second component</h1>
        )
    }
}

class all extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <section><First /><Second /></section>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<all />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Have you put a `<div id="root"></div>` in your view ?

Comment: Yes. This is my HTML -

Comment: <code> <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
  </body>
</html> </code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jsx component names starting with `lowercase` are considered to be HTML elements.

Changing `all` to `All` should work fine.

Please refer the answer,
[ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)