# React-Native Redux store root component error: 'looking for an class component, gets an object object'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

This works:

```
const Router = connect()(Router);

// --- your exported main router
export default class MyExportedRouter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router scenes={scenes} />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

But if I change

```
const Router = connect()(Router);
...
<Router scenes={scenes} />
...
```

to

```
const myConnectedRouter = connect()(Router);
...
<myConnectedRouter scenes={scenes} />
...
```

It fails with the following error:

> looking for an class component, gets an object object

My full code is here:
https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/REDUX_FLUX.md

Comment: can you add bit of `your` code here?

Comment: How is the `myconnectedroutes` component defined? Please add the part of your code where you define this component to your question.

Comment: its same as official doc of RNRF. I have followed all instructions and imported proper files etc.

Answer (score 0):

`myConnectedRouter` should be capitalized, as in `MyConnectedRouter`

`connect()` returns a 'higher order React component class' (https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)

React components must be capitalized (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)

This question has been addressed in the context of ReactJS here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505/1905712