# React Native JSX export import identifier

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I encounter a strange issue when I `export` a `const` to another js file. Here is my issue:

Imagine I have two files named `index.js` and `router.js`.

```
// in router.js
export const stackNav = StackNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: Me,
    navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Welcome'
    }
}
});


// in index.js
import { stackNav } from './router';

class MainApp extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <stackNav />
       );
    }
}

export default MainApp;
```

When I use the above code to run, I fail to run my app and it shows error message with red screen: `Expected a component class, got [object Object].`

However, if I change all `stackNav` to `StackNav`, I can run my app successfully. So, I don't know why the case of the name/identifier matters?

Comment: This will answer your question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

Comment: @NeelGala your comment is the correct answer to my question and my question is duplicated of the thread your provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because React/ReactNative component name must begin with capital letters

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Offical [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html),

> **User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized**
>
> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement.
>
> Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.

The following are the code snippet from the doc.

```
import React from 'react';

// Wrong! This is a component and should have been capitalized:
function hello(props) {
// Correct! This use of <div> is legitimate because div is a valid HTML tag:
  return <div>Hello {props.toWhat}</div>;
}

function HelloWorld() {
  // Wrong! React thinks <hello /> is an HTML tag because it's not capitalized:
  return <hello toWhat="World" />;
}
```