# How to call/access React.FC from other file - Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

code -

```
const Exne: React.FC <IProps> = ({x}) => 
    {
    console.log('input', x);    
    const [getx, assignx] = useState(x);
    console.log(getx, assignx);
    return(getx)
    };
```

In this code, how to access or call `Exne` from other files?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting functions with reactjs and babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309306/exporting-functions-with-reactjs-and-babel)

Answer (score 0):

You can **export** the const and **import** it in another file you want to use.

in `file.ts`:

```typescript
export const Exne: React.FC <IProps> = ({x}) => {
    console.log('input', x);    
    const [getx, assignx] = useState(x);
    console.log(getx, assignx);
    return(getx)
};
```

in `another.ts`:

```typescript
import { Exne } from './file';

// and you can use Exne as you are in file.ts
```