# How to use a dynamically created component into a JSX snippet in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component (*Section*) that render a list of *Field* components:

```
class Section extends React.Component  {

    renderFields() {
        const subfields = this.props.data_fields || [];
        const fieldsList = subfields.map((field_data) =>
            this.addField(field_data)
        );

        return (
            fieldsList
        )
    }

    addField(field_data) {
        return (
            <Field name='foo' type='bar' />
        )   
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.renderFields()}
        </div>;
    }

}
```

I would like to replace the addField method, using a dynamically created Component like this:

```
    addField(field_data) {
    ....

        let field = new Field({name: name, type: type})  // Component, not ReactElement
    ....
    // Some logic using 'field' here....

        return (
            {field}
        )
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {field}).

So I tried to modified the return into:

```
        return (
            <div>
                {field.render()}
            </div>
        )
```

This output correctly on the page, but when I explore the DOM with [React Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en), the element became a  (previously it was a )

I think I do it wrong because when later-on I change the state of one of these dynamically added Field, I get the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the Field component.

How can I use a dynamically created component into a JSX snippet ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with creating components yourself?

Comment: I need to store the reference of this dynamically created component into a list owned by a top-level component. (for information, it is a leaf of a multi-level tree)

Comment: Try using a capital letter, as in `let FieldInstance = new Field({...})`, then just return the `FieldInstance` component as itself <FieldIntance />. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters, otherwise JSX won't parse it as a component

Comment: Thanks @lux for your answer. When I do: `return (
            FieldInstance
        )` I get the following error: `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {props, context, refs, updater, state}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap....`

Comment: why aren't you using refs?

Comment: Looks like `Field` is an object, and not a component. More code would be helpful

Comment: @pwolaq: I can't use refs since I populate dynamically a tree, and I need to store somewhere in my root component a flat-list of references on all the leaves of this tree