# React-Router v4 <Route render={...} /> not displaying component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm trying to work though a quick app to get a better undestanding of React-Router v4.  Right now my plan is to just have a form one one page that populated a second page based on inputs.

I'm trying to pass two functions, onNameChange and onEmailChange, through the App component down to the vCardForm component.  In trying to follow this example: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4627 I found that my component does not even load using the render={...} property.  Below is my code, any help would be appreciated.

*components/App/index.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from '../Header';
import Main from '../Main';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: ''
    }

    this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onEmailChange = this.onEmailChange.bind(this);
  }

  onNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ name: event.target.value })
  }

  onEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Main />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*components/Main/index.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import vCardForm from '../vCardForm';

import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      onNameChange,
      onEmailChange
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <main className="App-intro">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (
            <vCardForm />
          )} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    )
  }
}

export default Main;
```

*components/vCardForm/index.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class vCardForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <p>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name: </label>
          <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email: </label>
          <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </p>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default vCardForm;
```

Comment: https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/src/index.jsx here's an example on how I use react-router-4. I don't know if it's because you're not returning the component, but if you aren't passing any props, I'd simply the `<Route exact path="/" component={vCardForm} />`. Also, I don't know if the Switch covers it, but shouldn't it be wrapped in a <Router> component?

Comment: You need to capitalize the component name to VCardForm or it will be interpreted as an html tag - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters

Comment: You MUST start a component name with a Captial letter.

Comment: @TestWell ah... cant believe i missed that one!  Thank you, that solved the missing component issue

Answer (score 1):

In your `App.js`, you aren't passing any props to `<Main />` in the render method. Try the same code with:

```
<Main onNameChange={this.onNameChange} onEmailChange={this.onEmailChange} />
```

Taking into consideration the previous comments, you should capitalize all components. Then, pass the same props into the render prop of the `<Route/>`:

```
<Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (
   <VCardForm {...props}/>
)} />
```

Also keep in mind that the `exact` prop on `Route` means that you need to be on the route `/` exactly. As in you'll need to be on `https://localhost:3000/` assuming you're using port `3000` to serve your app.