# ReactDOM.render Not Rendering anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my main file I have this code

```
import phoneReactElement from "../components/phone.js";

ReactDOM.render(<phoneReactElement />, document.getElementById('phoneComponentTester'));
```

"../components/phone.js" looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class TestComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>IT WORKED</div>
        );
    }

}
export default TestComponent;
```

It seems like its working correctly, because there's no errors in the console, and I can see the element in google chrome tools, but it seems to be empty. It doesn't show "IT WORKED", what am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: This works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/xfThQCIsF3PAc0OA2GTo?p=preview Can you double-check you're importing the right `phone.js`?

Comment: Thanks for putting that together, it seems one difference could be that I'm exporting the component (I think I'm doing this correctly). I confirmed that phone.js is correct.

Comment: I answered this below, but just noticed this is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters

Comment: I tried your code in a new project, and the first issue was that it looks like your `components` folder isn't inside the `src` folder but next to it. That's not allowed. I moved it inside and changed the path from `..` to `.` and I got a blank page and an empty `phonereactelement` element. Then I changed `phoneReactElement` to `PhoneReactElement` in `index.js`, and presto, "IT WORKED". My advice would be to use `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import phoneReactElement from "../components/phone.js";
```

needs to be :

```
import TestComponent from "../components/phone.js";
```

and to render it :

```
ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById('phoneComponentTester'));
```

Comment: Well thank you for the response, but I tried your fixes it and it didn't seem to make any difference. I think since its the default export it shouldn't matter what I name it?

Comment: You right but the consistency is important and you shouldnt start your component with a lower case letter check @djfdev answer

Comment: I agree, it should be upper case, I just wish it displayed it worked. It looks like there's nothing wrong with my code according to your examples.

Comment: try to wrap the `div` tag inside another div

Comment: Thanks for your help Amr!

Answer (score 0):

JSX treats lowercase tags as regular HTML tags. You should rename `phoneReactElement` to `PhoneReactElement` or something else that starts with an uppercase letter.

See [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I can see that its being rendered, if you look at the screenshot I attached, it seems to indicate that. I renamed it to be `PhoneReactElement` and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in the link I provided ... I also confirmed that changing it to your version will render an empty, invalid HTML element called phonereactelement