# Unable to render a component from other component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

I am trying to render a component from other component, but failing miserable, Can someone please help me with code and help me understand what i am doing wrong? 
Also, using the following example, can someone help me understand when to use type=text/jsx or type=text/babel?

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Flask React</h1>
  <br>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js"></script>
<script type="text/jsx">

  /*** @jsx React.DOM */

  var realPython = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (<realPython1 />);
    }
  });

  var realPython1 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (<h2>Greetings, from Real Python!</h2>);
    }
  });


  ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(realPython, null),
    document.getElementById('content')
  );

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Use capital component names! Or else they'll be treated as DOM elements!

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters

Answer (score 0):

Hey man I did some refactoring on your code, maybe take a look at the react docs they are pretty awesome eitherway here's your code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">

              var RealPython = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                  return <RealPython1 />
                }
              });

              var RealPython1 = React.createClass({
                render: function() {
                  return <h2>Greetings, from Real Python!</h2>;
                }
              });


              ReactDOM.render(
                React.createElement(RealPython),
                document.getElementById('content')
              );

            </script>
</body>
```

Comment: is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @Cruiser I'm helping with the code

Comment: @DimitrisKirtsios i am new to this technology, really appreciate you help, Thanks

Comment: @anonymous No problem, try the docs too for any other questions react is well documented

Answer (score 0):

First you probably don't want to be using jstransform any longer, it has been deprecated: https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html

Instead you should use a transpiler like babel: https://babeljs.io/

Once you are transpiling your code then you just write javascript so you can just use script type "text/javascript" instead of either "text/jsx" or "text/babel".

Below is an example of how to render a component within a component.

```js
class SubComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h2>A cool sub-component</h2>
    </div>;
  }
}

class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h2>Greetings, from Real Python!</h2>
      <SubComponent />
    </div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></app>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @socketwiz . It really cleared a lot things. Just one more small query, when i am trying to keep 'application' and 'subcomponent' in 2 different files, and importing subcomponent, i am getting an error `` require is not defined`` in my console. Any idea, why?

Comment: Yeah, you need a way to define require and import.  A lot of people use webpack (https://webpack.js.org/) for this, but now you're getting into deep water.  As a beginner I would recommend something like "Create React App" which will manage all of this for you so all you have worry about is your code (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).