# Render large number of components from a wrapper array allComponents

Tags: reactjs

I found myself in a situation where the number of components start to get annoying. So I put them in a wrapper file:

```
import CreateDatabaseTask from './tasks/CreateDatabaseTask'
import CreateMigrationsTask from './tasks/CreateMigrationsTask'
...

export const allTasks = [
    CreateDatabaseTask,
    CreateMigrationsTask
    ...
]
```

Next, in my tasklist I do

```
import {allTasks} from './tasks/allTasks'
```

But in the render() method I am not sure how to populate a div from the allTasks array?

I have tried to map the array into Components but cant figure out how to set the component name implicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map the array.

```js
function one() {
  return <p>One</p>
}
function two() {
  return <p>Two</p>
}

const array = [one, two]

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       {
         array.map(Number=><Number/>)
       }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Remember to use argument starting with Capital letter as `React` only recognises components with this approach. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505/4374566

Comment: Thanks, the capital letter got me!