# How to set element name dynamically in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How can I set element name dynamically in reactjs ? I'm using this [library](https://github.com/kirillshevch/react-cryptocoins) to show cryptocurrecy icons as a list. Using the library we can get Bitcoin icon as `<Btc />` and so on. Lets say I've define an array of Cryptocurrency names(Btc, Eth, Sc etc) as a state call `crypto`. Using `map` function how can I set the element name dynamically ?

```
render(){
 return(
  <div>
   {this.state.crypto.map( crypto => {
    <h3>{crypto}</h3>
    <{crypto} />
   }
  </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use variable as tag [(the only requirement is that variable starts with uppercase letter)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505/2048417):

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.crypto.map(Crypto => (
                <div>
                    <h3>{crypto}</h3>
                    <Crypto />
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error.

`Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Crypto]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h3 (at currency_main.js:44)
    in div (at currency_main.js:43)
    in div (at currency_main.js:41)
    in CryptoList (at App.js:10)
    in div (at App.js:9)
    in App (at index.js:8)`

Comment: This will only work if the array contains a list of types (aka Components), and not strings of names.

Comment: @omerts in your case it will behave the same, there is no workaround other than passing functions

Comment: @pwolaq Correct, my bad :)

Comment: So, @pwolaq can't I use this if I'm using an array of strings ?

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana no, you can't - React does not support such syntax because there is no guarantee your function/class names won't be scrambled when using some kind of optimizers.

Comment: @pwolaq Thanks a lot for the clarification. This worth more.
Anyway solved the issue by using a separate library which shows the currency icons using CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the name dynamically using `React.createElement` function. JSX is just synthetic sugaring over the `createElement` function.

```
render() {    
 return (
  <div>
   {this.state.crypto.map(crypto => {
      const cryptoElement = React.createElement(crypto)
      return <div>
        <h3>{crypto}</h3>
        {cryptoElement}
      </div>
    })}
  </div>
 )
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omerts/Lagja2sy/

Here you can find the documentation about it:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

Comment: Hey, I checked in jsfiddle it works fine. But when I add it to my code it gives me an error saying 

`Warning: <Eth /> is using uppercase HTML. Always use lowercase HTML tags in React.
Warning: The tag <Eth> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.`

gives this error for all the array elements as they start in capital letters (as should the elements). 

Anyway, solved my issue by using a seperate library which use CSS classes.

Comment: Ok, if you want to try to solve your above issue anyways, please post some more of your code. Preferably, post a fiddle.