# ReactJS - why is my nested element not rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render a nested component `friendPanel` from within my `App` component. It is compiling but upon loading, is not showing the friendPanel's array. I'm a reactJS newbie, so please bear with me. How should I render the friendPanel from within the App component?

The relevant parts of my code are below:

```
class friendPanel extends Component {
  render(props) {
    return (
      <ul>
        {props.friends.map( friend =>
          <li key={friend.id}>{friend.name}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = { 
    name: 'Bob McBobberson',
    friendList: [
      {id: 1, name: "Sandra"}, 
      {id: 2, name: "Tammy"}, 
      {id: 3, name: "Fernando"}
    ],
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1>Welcome {this.state.name}</h1>
          </header>
          <friendPanel friends={this.state.friendList} />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe try this.props instead of props... I haven’t seen it done your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
class FriendPanel extends Component {   //fixed - Component name should start with an upper-case letter
  render() {   // removed the unnecessary props parameter
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.friends.map( friend =>  //fixed - in ReactJS, this is the way we get data from props
          <li key={friend.id}>{friend.name}</li>
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = { 
    name: 'Bob McBobberson',
    friendList: [
      {id: 1, name: "Sandra"}, 
      {id: 2, name: "Tammy"}, 
      {id: 3, name: "Fernando"}
    ],
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1>Welcome {this.state.name}</h1>
          </header>
          <FriendPanel friends={this.state.friendList} />   //fixed -  in JSX, the custom element must start with an upper-case or the compiler will treat this as regular html tag
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this was extremely helpful, my code is working as expected now, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You should capitalize `FriendPanel` or React will treat it as plain old HTML.

See: [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

Comment: feeling very silly for not having realized this. Thank you!