# cannot access state in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, render, react-google-maps

I am using library react-google-maps, and i want to use DirectionsRenderer between two nodes.
Here is my state

```
this.state={
    currentPosition:{lat: 26.84 ,lng: 75.80},
    destinationPosition:{lat: 26.84 ,lng: 75.80},
};
```

I want to show the direction between my current location and marker. And my componentDidMount() is inside render method.
Here is the code for render method

```
class map extends React.PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            currentPosition:{lat: 26.84 ,lng: 75.80},
            destinationPosition:{lat: 26.84 ,lng: 75.80},
            direction:false
        };
    }
    onMarkerPositionChanged(e){
        this.setState((state)=>({
            destinationPosition:{lat:e.latLng.lat(),lng:e.latLng.lng()}}));
    }
    handleClick(){
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position)=>{
                this.setState(()=>({
                    currentPosition:{lat:position.coords.latitude,lng:position.coords.longitude}}))
            }); 
        }
        else{
            alert("Geoloaction is not supported by your browser");
        }
    }
    changeDir(){
        if(this.state.direction)
            this.setState(()=>({direction:false}))
        else
            this.setState(()=>({direction:true}))
    }
    render(){
        const MyMapComponent = compose(
          withProps({
            googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5VMMlyr_A6K5ycpOrq3OsVM8YYbn0q3A&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
            loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
            containerElement: <div style={{ height: `300px` }} />,
            mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
          }),
          withScriptjs,
          withGoogleMap,
          lifecycle({       
            componentDidMount() {
                const google=window.google;
                console.log(this.state);
//--->this statement prints null
                const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                DirectionsService.route({
                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(this.state.currentPosition.lat, this.state.currentPosition.lng),
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(this.state.destinationPosition.lat,this.state.destinationPosition.lng),
//---->  this is where i want to use the state to get the direction between //current location and marker
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
                }, (result, status) => {
                if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                  this.setState({
                    directions: result,
                  });
                } else {
                  console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
                }
              });
            }
          })
        )(
        props =>
          <GoogleMap defaultZoom={15} defaultCenter={this.state.destinationPosition} >
            <Marker position={this.state.destinationPosition} draggable changeLat
                onDragEnd={this.onMarkerPositionChanged.bind(this)}
            />
            <Marker
                icon="https://www.robotwoods.com/dev/misc/bluecircle.png"
                position={this.state.currentPosition}
            />
            {this.state.direction && props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions} />}
            <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Current Position</Button>
            <Button bsStyle="success" onClick={this.changeDir.bind(this)}>Get Direction</Button>
          </GoogleMap>
        );
        return(
            <Container state={this.state} map={MyMapComponent}/>
        );
    }
}
export default map;
```

when i use constant numbers in place of origin and destination it works fine.

Comment: try `state = {...}` instead of `this.state = {...}`

Comment: it's not working, i tried console.log(state); it is giving error of state is not defined.

Comment: @rajatgalav this looks a bit weird... could you please post your entire component?

Comment: @c-chavez i have edited my code again.

Comment: @rajatgalav so, the issue here is that `this` is out of context when you access it, which can be easily fixed. The problem is I don't really understand some things, for example, why is that `componentdidMount` function inside the `lifecycle`? is this a feature or something you can actually do with this library? If you can show us a link where you got this example it would also be helpful.

Comment: @c-chavez i used library react-google-maps and link is https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, change the name of the component `map` to `Map`. Have a read [at this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters).

Now, regarding this:

> when i use constant numbers in place of origin and destination it works fine.

The answer to this question has a background, continue reading the following so that it is more clear.

**The problem of the `this` context**

In your code, you have a `map` component, and you can access any of its properties (including the state) with `this`. If you call `this.state` inside the `render` function for example, you will get the state of `map`. You can use the `componentDidMount` function of the `map` component, to, for example, set a value in the state, like this:

```
class map extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    this.state = { myVal: 1}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({ myVal: 2})
  }
}
```

This code will not fail, because componentDidMount is a React function for the component, and `this` can be used inside the component because it's in the same context. In this case, `this.setState` will set the state of `map`, because `this` is `map`.

This is the code of [the example you provided](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#directionsrenderer):

```
const { compose, withProps, lifecycle } = require("recompose"); const {   withScriptjs,   withGoogleMap,   GoogleMap,   DirectionsRenderer, } = require("react-google-maps");

const MapWithADirectionsRenderer = compose(   withProps({
    googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC4R6AN7SmujjPUIGKdyao2Kqitzr1kiRg&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,   }),   withScriptjs,   withGoogleMap,   lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

      DirectionsService.route({
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8507300, -87.6512600),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8525800, -87.6514100),
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      }, (result, status) => {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          this.setState({
            directions: result,
          });
        } else {
          console.error(`error fetching directions ${result}`);
        }
      });
    }   }) )(props =>   <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={7}
    defaultCenter={new google.maps.LatLng(41.8507300, -87.6512600)}
  >
    {props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions} />}   </GoogleMap> );

<MapWithADirectionsRenderer />
```

In this example, `this.setState` refers to the context of `MapWithADirectionsRenderer`, so `this.setState` is setting the state of `MapWithADirectionsRenderer`, because `this` is `MapWithADirectionsRenderer`.

Now, in your code you are creating a new component called `MyMapComponent` as a const object. This component lets you define the `componentDidMount` function of that new component. That new component will have it's own context, so when you write `this` inside the `MyMapComponent` component, it will refer to `MyMapComponent`, not to `map`.

You cannot access the state of `map` from within `MyMapComponent` like that, you have to pass props to `MyMapComponent`.

### **Solution**

I created a couple of examples on how to pass values.

**Solution 1**

You can create a prop with any name (in this example it's called test with the value `My value`):

```
const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5VMMlyr_A6K5ycpOrq3OsVM8YYbn0q3A&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    test:'My value'
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.test));
    }
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
    {props.isMarkerShown && (
      <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
));
```

This way, you can log `this.props.test` with the given value, whatever you use.

**Solution 2**

If what you need is to render the component depending on the value found in the state of `Map`, use something like this.

You can pass props to `MyMapComponent` an then access them using `props.` and adding the name of the prop.

For example if you pass a new prop called `latProp` like this:

```
<MyMapComponent isMarkerShown latProp={-34.397} />
```

You can access it like this:

```
(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
    {props.isMarkerShown && (
      <Marker position={{ lat: props.latProp, lng: 150.644 }} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
));
```

Since what you want is to replace the constant value with what you have in the state, just replace the values sent in `props.latProp` with whatever property you have in the state:

```
<MyMapComponent isMarkerShown latProp={this.state.lat} />
```

This is the complete component:

```
const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC5VMMlyr_A6K5ycpOrq3OsVM8YYbn0q3A&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
)(props => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
    {props.isMarkerShown && (
      <Marker position={{ lat: props.latProp, lng: props.lngProp }} />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
));

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { lat: -34.400, lng: 151.644 }
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <MyMapComponent isMarkerShown latProp={this.state.lat} lngProp={this.state.lng} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```