# Properly giving names to components without it being too long

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am at loss how to name my components so that it would look good on the page and not have super long names. For example, I have an app where I have a UsersSidebar component and inside there are User components. But I also have a UserList and inside there is also User components but different components. And then I may have another different User component on the page. So they are 3 different User components but they are all called User. How could I solve this problem?

Should I call it *users-sidebar-user* and user-list-user because that looks very long and clunky. What if I have 2 different *user-sidebar* components? Should I call it *general-user-sidebar* and *forum-user-sidebar* and then *forum-user-sidebar-user*?

```
// Here the <user> is a sidebar item <li>username</li>
<users-sidebar>
    <user>
    <user>
    <user>
</users-sidebar>

// Here the <user> is a different component <div><h1>username</h1></div
<user-list>
    <user>
    <user>
    <user>
</user-list>


// And here <user> is <div class="card">username</user>
<user>
```

Comment: I can't see any possible component names here... ["In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. However, lower-case tag names with a dot (property accessor) aren't."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505/14357)

Comment: If `UserSidebar` is local to *users* feature and cannot be confused with other sidebars in the app, it can be named `Sidebar`. And so on. You can always do `Sidebar as UserSidebar` on import if there's ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airbnb has a React Styling guide that could be helpful to you:

[Airbnb React Styleguide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#naming)

Good luck with your naming! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try refactor your directory i.e. create a folder named user then create different components in it and bootstrap them in /User/Index.js. This way you will be able to skip 'user-' in files.

Hope it helps.