# ReactJS with MaterialUI dialog: Testing using Jest Enzyme shallow text return empty

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I have this React component having Material UI Dialog

Using Full screen dialog from here https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog';
import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions';
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText';
import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle';
import withMobileDialog from '@material-ui/core/withMobileDialog';

class Template extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { fullScreen } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>count: 0</p>
        { <Dialog
          fullScreen={fullScreen}
          open={true}
          aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
        >
          <DialogTitle id="responsive-dialog-title">
            Title Here
          </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText>Text Here</DialogContentText>
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button id='cnfbtn'>Confirm</Button>
            <Button id='closebtn' autoFocus>Cancel</Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog> }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Template.propTypes = {
  fullScreen: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default withMobileDialog()(Template);
```

and trying to run this test on it

```
    import React from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
    import Template from '../common/template';

    describe('template.js', () => {
      it('Renders template success ', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Template />);
        console.log('wrapper:::::', wrapper);
        console.log('wrapper.text:::::', wrapper.text());
        const text = wrapper.find('p').text();
        expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
        expect(text).toContain('count: 0');
      });
    });
```

Getting following error.

```
     ● Console

    console.log src/components/__tests__/template.js:8
      wrapper::::: ShallowWrapper {}
    console.log src/components/__tests__/template.js:9
      wrapper.text::::: <WithWidth(WithMobileDialog) />

  ● template.js › Renders template success

    Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

       8 |     console.log('wrapper:::::', wrapper);
       9 |     console.log('wrapper.text:::::', wrapper.text());
    > 10 |     const text = wrapper.find('p').text();
         |                                    ^
      11 |     expect(wrapper.length).toEqual(1);
      12 |     expect(text).toContain('count: 0');
      13 |   });
```

Running test using this command

```
eslint src && react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage
```

App is created using create react app https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

```
"@types/jest": "^23.3.12",
"enzyme": "^3.8.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
"react-scripts": "2.1.3",
"react": "^16.7.0",
```

try to use https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html as well but did not help

Comment: You have a higher order component, `withMobileDialog`, that's wrapping your `Template` component. Since you're only shallow wrapping it, it'll only show this HOC. The easiest work around is to export the class template (`export class Template extends Component`) and then `import { Template } from 'path/to/template';`. Please note that this will NOT replace your `default` export! Otherwise, you'll need to use `mount` instead of `shallow`. You can see the `DOM` as enzyme seeing it by writing `console.log(wrapper.debug());`.

Comment: Makes complete sense @MattCarlotta Many Thanks