# Problem importing stateless function is react

Tags: reactjs

I am very new to react and having a bizarre problem. I have defined a stateless function and when i want to try to import it in my main component it is not loading the function. i am guessing there is a naming convention that i dont know of. npm start does not give any error so I am assuming the code is compiling ok.

My stateless component is below

```
import React from 'react';

const AppHeader = () => {
    return(

            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Map Search</h1>
            <p>Searching map for nearest matches from account</p> 
            </div>

    );
}

export default AppHeader;
```

below does not work,

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import appHeader from './UI/appHeader';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){

    return (      
      <div className="App">
        <appHeader/>
      </div>
    );
  }


}

export default App;
```

VS code lint says

> appHeader is declared but its value is never used.

However below does work,

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import KKK from './UI/appHeader';

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){

    return (      
      <div className="App">
        <KKK/>
      </div>
    );
  }


}

export default App;
```

VS code lint does not show the error anymore also the app is working as expected. As you can see i only changed the name of the appHeader component to KKK. can someone point out what am i doing wrong and may be provide any documentation around this.

Comment: You might need to capitalize `appHeader` to be `AppHeader`

Answer (score 3):

You need to capitalize `appHeader` to be `AppHeader` in order for React to understand that this is a custom component and not a built in html component. Components that start with lowercase are assumed to be built in HTML elements.

Check out this answer: [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

And from the React docs:

> User-Defined Components Must Be Capitalized
>
> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.
>
> We recommend naming components with a capital letter. If you do have a component that starts with a lowercase letter, assign it to a capitalized variable before using it in JSX.