# Can we include one or more self closing components in one main App.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

**Can we include one or more self closing components in one main App.js file in reactjs**

1. I just created one react app i just wanted to include one more in one file(self closing component thing) means i created one component card.js and after that i included that component in main(App.js) file can i include another navbar.js component in that file .i did that but not showing anything it showing as it is means previous component things displays but another second file component not showing why this happening .?? [image: images for detailing i think i need Router]

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You component needs to be rendered in a way that their names start with `first letter as uppercase`. You can have as many self closing elements as you want within a component

```
import Social from './components/social';
function App() {
  return (
     <div>
       <Jumbotron />
       <Social />
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: it worked i am trying using small case but as you said it needs to be in firs letter in capitalcase it worked upvoted/appreciated

Comment: Glad to have helped

Comment: Your Answer approved

Answer (score 1):

Try with a capital letter, otherwise the component will not be rendered correctly, as Shubham Khatri has shown in the example

Comment: My Question is related to fragments in reactjs find more things here https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html