# Unable to render child component in App.js using React

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to React and am having trouble rendering a component in `App.js`. After much googling I still don't know why I am just getting a blank white page in the browser instead of a printed piece of text as shown in `component1.js`. Here's my code:

*component1.js*

```
import React from 'react';

class component1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>It's a bit chilly out there</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default component1;
```

*App.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {component1} from './component1.js';

class App extends React.component{

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <component1 />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Could anyone please steer me towards the right path and tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: React components must start with capital letter!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong case :

```js
class App extends React.Component
------------------------↑
```

Also, `component1` must be imported as a default import (not a named import) with a capital letter :

```js
import Component1 from './component1.js';
```