# I got the problem in using React Hook - useDispatch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "loginForm" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

I got this kind of message.
Attached code...

```
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch} from 'react-redux'

const loginForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  
  return (
    <div>lgoinForm</div>
  )
}

export default loginForm
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `loginForm` to **LoginForm** (component should start with a capital letter).

I have tested your code and it works fine after naming the component correctly.

Read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

Answer (score 1):

You can make the loginForm to **useLoginForm** it should be a custom hook name starting with use keyword.