# Allowed characters in Reactjs component names

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-component

What are the rules for naming components in Reactjs?

I am aware that component names must start with a capital letter, but what else?

What I'd like to do is namespace the components of my PP library, for example have all the names start with "PP_" or "PP.".

I use JSX, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Other than react component names being PascalCased, I believe the rest fall under plain old vanilla JS identifier requirements/restrictions.

Comment: [related old docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component), which state: "_Note: Always start component names with a capital letter. \[...\]_"

Answer (score 2):

There is no official style guide for naming react components. Most of the people follow pascal-case.
Below is the link of popular airbnb style guide.
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#naming

Comment: um... what? https://stackoverflow.com/q/30373343/11107541