# Why I got such an warning into the console i.e The tag buttton is unrecognized in this browser

Tags: reactjs

Here is my code

```
const templateOne = <div>
    <h1>{app.heading}</h1>
    <p>{app.subHeading}</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Item One</li>
        <li>Item Two</li>
    </ol>
    <form>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <buttton>addOptions</buttton>
    </form>
</div>

ReactDom.render(templateOne, document.getElementById('root))
```

Then I got the warning i.e react-dom.development.js:82 Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter in buttton,in form,in div

Comment: buttton with triple t?

Comment: The error message could *not* be any clearer. React components need to start with an uppcercase letter. So `templateOne` --> `TemplateOne`

Answer (score 1):

Correct the spelling of `<button>`

Man I also got the same warning first..

The problem is that all react components should start with an **Uppercase** letter.

If you change `templateOne` to `TemplateOne` then it should be fine.

Also change it here.

```
ReactDom.render(TemplateOne, document.getElementById('root))
```

The warning should disappear.

Comment: If this answer is helpful then please mark this as **Accepted Answer**. It would mean a lot to me

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:-

```
const MyComponent = <div>
    <h1>{app.heading}</h1>
    <p>{app.subHeading}</p>
    <ol>
        <li>Item One</li>
        <li>Item Two</li>
    </ol>
    <form>
        <input type="text"></input>
        <button>addOptions</buttton>
    </form>
</div>


ReactDom.render(MyComponent, document.getElementById('root));
```

If the component is creating with the lowercase, react will take it as a normal Html tag. So always create your component starting with uppercase.

read more - [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)