# Data not visible in react function - Why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am new to React and playing with it to get familiar.

I have a component that simply puts a header and a data grid which is called in from another component.

Main component :

```
import './App.css';
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {Container,Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import aboutData from './aboutData';

function About() {
  **const [name, setName]= "This is the name"**
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>About page with aboutData</h1>
        <aboutData data = {name}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Other function :

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react'
import {Container,Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

function aboutData({data}) {
  return (
    <li>
        <h3>Inside grid component</h3>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>{this.data }</Col>
          <Col xs={6}>{this.data}</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>1 of 3</Col>
          <Col xs={5}>2 of 3 (wider)</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </li> 
  );
}

export default aboutData;
```

I am passing a test value "This is the name" but `aboutData` class never renders.
Could some one show me where am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Capitalize the component

Comment: you don't need `this` keyword to access props. just use `data` in your aboutData component. Because you are using functional component and destructuring. `aboutData({data})`

Comment: Here's a good explanation as to why lowercase component names don't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Here is have attached the working code. Yes, I understood that now there is a difference between lower case and upper case component names thanks to Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Working code that passes parameter name from Parent component to chile component. **Component names should start with an Upper case letter.** In my case, it should be **'AboutData'** not 'aboutData'.

Parent :

```
import './App.css';
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {Container,Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import AboutData from './AboutData';

function About() {
  const [name, setName]= useState('This is the name from hook');


  return (
    <div>
        <h1>About page with aboutData</h1>
        {/* <AboutData data = {name}/> */}
        <AboutData data = {name}/>
        </div>
  );
}

export default About;
```

Child :

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react'
import {Container,Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';

// function AboutData({data}) {
function AboutData({data}) {
  return (
    <li>
        <h3>Inside grid component</h3>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>{data}</Col>
          <Col xs={6}>2</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>1 of 3</Col>
          <Col xs={5}>2 of 3 (wider)</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </li> 
  );
}

export default AboutData;
```