# React imports/exports

Tags: reactjs, import, export

So, I am trying to export this function to my main React App.js folder but it works only when the function name is in Uppercase. This is very strange since I have never encountered this behavior. This is the code that does not work:

```
export const family = () => {
  return <p>gfdgdfgfdgdfgdf</p>;
};

import import { family } from "./PersonInfo/PersonInfo.js";
```

//in my class component in App.js I am using this JSX: `<family/>`

However, when I try this code, it works:

```
export const Family = () => {
  return <p>dfgfdgfdgdf</p>;
};

import { Family } from "./PersonInfo/PersonInfo.js";
```

//in my class component in App.js I am using this JSX: `<Family/>`

What is wrong with using a lower case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because user-defined components must be capitalized.
https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Edit: Your question is actually related to [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of that. I have been until now using only default components and it functioned well with lower case. Thanks!