# Using reactj with Redux and hook

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have this component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import inputAction from '../../redux/actions/inputActions';
import clienteActions from '../../redux/actions/clientesAction';

const clientes = () => { 
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const clientes = useSelector(state => state.clientes.clientes);
    
    //.... more code
}
```

ant I have an error in this line:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

this is the error

```
src\components\clientes\clientes.js
  Line 7:22:  React Hook "useDispatch" is called in function "clientes" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 8:22:  React Hook "useSelector" is called in function "clientes" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

what I wrong???

Comment: Is your function `clientes` returning some React elements? How is it rendered?

Comment: `clientes` is not considered a React component - [try capitalizing it](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Comment: yes!!! I have a return

Comment: @chazsolo It work, I changed  name function and it work thanks

Answer (score 1):

All React component names must start with a **capital letter**. If you start a component name with a lowercase letter, it will be treated like a built-in element like a div or a span. This is because of the way JSX works.

Just **change Function to Clientes** and **don't forget to export** it.

Answer (score 0):

Hooks in react functional components have to be used in the main component function without conditions, loops, or callbacks.

Example of the useState hook:

```
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      Text
    </div>
  );
}
```

You have to move useDispatch hook **to the main component function**.

Answer (score 0):

**Rename component and component name must be as Uppercase**

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import inputAction from '../../redux/actions/inputActions';
import clienteActions from '../../redux/actions/clientesAction';

export const Clientes = () => { 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const clientes = useSelector(state => state.clientes.clientes);

    //.... more code
}
```

Comment: yes! It' work! thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is self-explanatory. In your error message, they are saying `... React component names must start with an uppercase letter ...`. So, your component is currently recognized as a normal function yet it's a component. Thus, if you mean it to be a react component, it has to start with an uppercase letter.

```
const Clientes = () => { 
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code look very okay expect for one thing: Your component name is in lowercase which is causing the error. In react, components i.e functions names must start with a capital letter. You can learn more about that and why that is the case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)