# React complement not being read

Tags: reactjs

Im begining to learn react and i having problems importing a complement. It does not show on the app nor shows any error.
This is the complement code:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";

const cardComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <img className="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap" />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">Card title</h5>
        <p className="card-text">
          Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
          bulk of the card's content.
        </p>
        <a href="#" className="btn btn-primary">
          Go somewhere
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default cardComponent;
```

And the app code is this:

```
import "./App.css";
import cardComponent from "./component/cardComponent";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <cardComponent />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Any tip would be apreciated

Comment: React component should be named starting with Capital Character. ex) `CardComponent`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to give you some tips:

Always start with:

```
   import React from 'react';
```

put the first sentence in capital like this:

```
 const CardComponent = () => {
  return (
   .
   .
   .

   export default CardComponent;
```

And in the App page you just import like this:

```
import CardComponent from './components/molecules/Card';

 const App = () => {
 return (
  <div className="App">
   <CardComponent />
  </div>
  );
 };
export default App;
```

I learned react with Typescript, so some it makes easier to avoid some issues, if you feel like it, I would advise to learn them together.

Answer (score 0):

This post solved the issue [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)
the error was not naming the compononent with initial capital letter

As was said in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68947275/16210502) to this post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30373505/16210502) answer given in the post mentioned before. React (jsx files) distinguishes tags between proper react components and html by their first letter (if it its capital it reads as a React component so:

```
<component /> compiles to React.createElement('component') (html tag)
<Component /> compiles to React.createElement(Component)
```

also

```
<obj.component /> compiles to React.createElement(obj.component)
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: thx for suggestions, the post was edited acording to them