# why isn't <navBar/> rendering? (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React.js, I'm trying to render a banner with a navbar underneath it  (basic stuff) but I can't figure it out.

#### My current navBar.js code

```js
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom";

export function navBar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className = "nav">
                <a>Upload Items</a>
                <a>New Items</a>
                <a>Textbooks</a>
                <a>Electronics</a>
                <a>Life</a>
                <a>Accessories</a>
                <a>others</a>
            </nav>
                
        </div>

    );
}
```

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {navBar} from './components/navBar'

function App() {
  
  //let [categories, setCategories] = useState(['textbooks', 'electronics', 'life', 'accessories', 'others'])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img className='logo' src={require('./revelliePicture.jpg')}/>
        <h1>Aggie Market</h1>
      </header>

      
      <navBar />
      
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

#### Current UI state

[image: what it currently looks like]

Comment: It might not be the cause but React components need to be named with PascalCase, not camelCase. So `NavBar` not `navBar`. And you should do a `export default NavBar` and then import as `import NavBar from './components/NavBar'`;

Answer (score 1):

This is because how React (Babel) differentiate between built in DOM components and user defined components. If your component doesn't start with capital letter its assumed that its a DOM component/ element, since there is no such DOM element, it does not work as expected.

Correct your naming and you will get the intended UI.

Read the official docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Comment: It's not React that does that but it's Babel while it transpiles JSX, it gets lower case as html and makes React.createElement(...) .

Comment: @CesarePolonara, Correct, I just used React ( now updated to included babel as well) just to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```js
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom";

export function navBar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className = "nav">
                <a>Upload Items</a>
                <a>New Items</a>
                <a>Textbooks</a>
                <a>Electronics</a>
                <a>Life</a>
                <a>Accessories</a>
                <a>others</a>
            </nav>
                
        </div>

    );
}
```

to:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ReactDOM } from "react-dom";

export function NavBar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className = "nav">
                <a>Upload Items</a>
                <a>New Items</a>
                <a>Textbooks</a>
                <a>Electronics</a>
                <a>Life</a>
                <a>Accessories</a>
                <a>others</a>
            </nav>
                
        </div>

    );
}
```

React Components name must begin with a ***Capital Case*** letter.

Then use it like: `<NavBar />`
Reasons of this beahviour: [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)