# Functional react component not rendering in another component when exported to Chrome debug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I want to render a component in another component. By directly exporting to a chrome debug window, I tested the following code:

```
function test() {
    return <p>Test</p>;
}

function app() {
    return <test />;
}

export default app;
```

I expect the result to be equivalent to:

```
function app() {
    return <p>Test</p>;
}

export default app;
```

Which should output:

[image: A blank webpage with the word 'Test']

Instead, I get this:

[image: A blank webpage with no content]

Any insight appreciated. I will provide additional information on request, but I am unsure what could be missing.

p.s. ignore blur on address bar, just using chrome account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first try capitalizing your components i.e.

```js
   function Test () {
     return <p>Test</p>
   }
   function App () {
     return <Test/>
   }
```

This could be a similar question: [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

Comment: By god, I had no clue that could even be an issue. Habits from C++. Thanks. I'll accept this in 2 minutes, as it tells me to wait.