# 'topSectionContainer' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am not completely sure where my mistake is since I just started learning React. The background image that I'm importing is not working and it might be due to the error I'm getting.

[snapshop of code and error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg9ET.png)   [picture of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm1fX.png)

Comment: `topSectionContainer` should be renamed as `TopSectionContainer` (both varaible and JSX), reason can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters

Comment: yes, i tried that, the error is gone but my image background is not showing.

Comment: use `background-image` instead of `background` property, that should do it

Comment: the screen is still blank.

Comment: Could you please update the images to check how your code looks now ? or create and share a code sandbox where people can check the issue, that would help anyone reading your question :)