# Unable to render component onClick event - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I am essentially to display a Login/Signup card when a user clicks on the sign up button of my website. However, the component I am trying to render on click is not showing up. Below is my code -

```js
import "./homePage.css";
import signupCard from "../signupCard/signupCard"; // .jsx file
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

function Header() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="header">
        <ul>
          <motion.li
            className="li__signup"
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              <signupCard />; // **trying to render card here**
            }}
          >
            Sign Up
          </motion.li>
          <motion.li
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
          >
            Contact
          </motion.li>
          <motion.li
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
          >
            About
          </motion.li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="../assets/image.png" alt="placeholder" />
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `Component` in react must be in the `render` and not in an `event` function.

Consider doing:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./homePage.css";
import signupCard from "../signupCard/signupCard"; // .jsx file
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

function Header() {
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {isOpened ? <signupCard /> : null} 
      <div className="header">
        <ul>
          <motion.li
            className="li__signup"
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              setIsOpened(true)
            }}
          >
            Sign Up
          </motion.li>
          <motion.li
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
          >
            Contact
          </motion.li>
          <motion.li
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
          >
            About
          </motion.li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="../assets/image.png" alt="placeholder" />
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing something similar. But now won't my card close if a user just clicks on a random place on the card? How do I prevent that?

Comment: It's not gonna happened but you may consider handle the `setIsOpened(false)` to close it somewhere.

Comment: Also, my card is still not rendered on click. I clicked on 'Go to Definition' in my editor to see if it knows what ```<signupCard />``` is. It says 'No definition found for signupCard'.

Comment: are you sure about the `import signupCard from "../signupCard/signupCard";`?

Comment: I have imported the component correctly. But it doesn't seem to recognise it when I use it.

Comment: Did you miss the capital `S` =>  `SignupCard`

Comment: Nope. I have named it ```signupCard```. As a matter of fact, I auto-imported ```signupCard```. So I don't think there are any typos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251929/discussion-between-harsh-darji-and-devpolo).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.

1. Return what you want to be rendered from your component. In this case return `SignupCard` from your component.
2. Use uppercase characters for react components. So `SignupCard` instead of `signupCard` (change it in the source file and the import). Refer to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

```js
import "./homePage.css";
import SignupCard from "../signupCard/signupCard"; // .jsx file
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useState } from "react";

function Header() {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      { opened ? <SignUpCard> : null }
      <div className="header">
        <ul>
          <motion.li
            className="li__signup"
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              setOpened(true);
            }}
          >
            Sign Up
          </motion.li>
          <motion.li
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
          >
            Contact
          </motion.li>
          <motion.li
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.05 }}
            whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
            transition={{ type: "spring", stiffness: 400, damping: 70 }}
          >
            About
          </motion.li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <img src="../assets/image.png" alt="placeholder" />
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```