# React App -App.js is not recognising a page

Tags: reactjs

I have defined `cartPage` function properly and got picked up in auto snippets within VS code but then this function is not recognized anymore anywhere.

I changed the name of the function from `cartPage` to `CartPage` then it worked.

Code attached :

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from '../components/DefaultLayout'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Table } from 'antd'

function cartPage() {
  const { cartItems } = useSelector((state) => state.rootReducer)

  const columns = [
    { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
    {
      title: 'Image',
      dataIndex: 'image',
      render: (image, record) => {
        <img src={image} alt='' height='60' width='60' />
      },
    },

    { title: 'Price', dataIndex: 'price' },
  ]

  return (
    <div>
      <DefaultLayout>
        <h3>Cart Summary</h3>
        <Table columns={columns} dataSource={cartItems} />
      </DefaultLayout>
    </div>
  )
}

    export default cartPage


import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Homepage from './pages/Homepage'
import Items from './pages/Items'
import cartPage from './pages/cartPage'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/home' element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route path='/items' element={<Items />} />
          <Route path='/cart' element={<cartPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: *"I changed name of the function from cartPage() to CartPage the it worked"* - Sounds like you've found the solution then.  React components should be capitalized anyway.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)

Comment: That's expected. Note: Always start component names with a capital letter. (from react docs - https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

Comment: From latest docs - Pitfall
React components are regular JavaScript functions, but their names must start with a capital letter or they won’t work! (https://react.dev/learn/your-first-component)

Comment: no i was following someone and they used small 'c' but their worked!