# Cannot import component in ReactJS with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

[image]

it says 'header' is declared but its value is never read.

```
import header from "./components/header.tsx";

function App() {
  return (
      <header />
  );
}

export default App;
```

tried changing path nothing happens

Comment: Custom React components are expected to be capitalised, lower case JSX is considered to be standard HTML not a React component. See: [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30373343/1650337)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React requires that the first letter of components be capitalized.

Take a look at the example below.

```
export function Header() {
      return (
            <>
              Header
            </>
      )
}
```

```
import { Header } from "./components/header.tsx";

function App() {
  return (
      <Header/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is incorrect, you're exporting a **named export** and importing it as a **default export**

Comment: Good catch, updated now.