# error in react child by udsing array in map function

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, children, react-children

i am trying to start coding a calculator in react by nextjs and tailwind, but in first step i got a problem .

this is main page code:

```
import Screen from './component/Screen'
import Wrapper from './component/wrapper'
import ButtonBox from './component/buttonBox'
import Button from './component/button'
const btnValues=[
  ["C","+-","%","/"],
  [7,8,9,"*"],
  [4,5,6,"-"],
  [1,2,3,"+"],
  [0,".","="],
]
console.log(btnValues);
export default function Home() {

  return (
    <Wrapper>
     <Screen />
      <ButtonBox> 
        {btnValues.flat().map((btn,i)=>{ return (
          <Button value={btn} key={i}/>)}
        )}
      </ButtonBox>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

as it is a array i try to use map , but i face a error which is:

"Internal error: Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

and also this is the ButtonBox content:

```
const buttonBox = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className='mt-16'>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default buttonBox
```

Wrapper is also the same as ButtonBox

i do not know what it means by using array  when i already used!

Comment: This code works perfectly and renders all the buttons you must be having this error from some other component

Answer (score 2):

Hey I have a couple of observations, regarding your code and a possible solution:

- Not sure what button.value is? What are you expecting to return? value does not exist in button, button is actually an array as well, if you want the values inside, you need to traverse the array again.
- You are going to get an error with that component sooner or later, not sure which version of react are you using, but need to start with Capital Letter, and cammel case. So it is "const ButtonBox" Check this here: [ReactJS component names must begin with capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373343/reactjs-component-names-must-begin-with-capital-letters)
- The flat declaration is wrong, it should be btnValues.map((btn,i) => { return (...)}).flat, but still that's not going to help you in this particular case, so going back to my first question, what output are you expecting?
- About the child Problem, what is sugested for A_mohii is the recommendable solution, however you can trick React, by declaring a constant with a pointer function and then call it in between your return{}

Anyways I did a full codesandbox, check if that's what you need, [check this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-cray-lp5vxc?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes, for button value, you are right. My mistake.

React 18: I changed the name to Kebab Case.

i was expecting to get items in btnvalue one by one and then sort them by grid. 
 thanks for trick thats works for me